# android notification bar when user is already in the correct spot

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, android-notifications

I have just been playing around with status bar notifications and am a bit stumped at what to do in the following situation:

I have an activity for displaying messages and a service which polls for new messages. When the service finds a new message it adds a notification to the status bar... all well and good. My question is: When the user is already in the messages activity, I probably don't want to add anything to the notification bar. I only want to add it if they are not looking at the messages at the time. I would think this is a common problem and am wondering if anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a static boolean variable in your Activity called `isRunning` that you set false when ever onPause is called, and true whenever onResume is called. It's simple and elegant :)